# Formula that provides multiple answers based on different outcomes in different cells

Tags: excel, formula

I have been banging my head against a brick wall trying to work out a formula, any help would be amazing!

SO....

I have three columns that work out annual leave.

```
COLUMN 1 = AMOUNT OF HOLIDAY A PERSON HAS REMAINING FOR THE YEAR

COLUMN 2 = AMOUNT OF HOLIDAY TAKEN IN REPORTING MONTH

COLUMN 3 = NEEDS A FORMULA TO WORK OUT IF THE PERSON HAS GONE OVER THEIR ANNUAL LIMIT, OR WHETHER SOME OF IT HAS, OR WHETHER THEY ARE ENTITLED TO THE FULL MONTHS ALLOCATION
```

Ie: If a person has taken 5 days holiday in `COLUMN B`, but in `COLUMN A` it is saying they have gone over their annual allowance by 2 days, the cell in COLUMN C needs to return zero (they dont get paid for holiday taken in Column 2 as they have already gone over their annual amount shown in `COLUMN A`)

If a person has taken 5 days in `COLUMN B`, but in COLUMN A they have 10 days remaining, `COLUMN C` should return 5 as they had 10 days remaining for the year, and taken 5 days in `COLUMN B`, so they are fine to be paid the 5 days they took

If a person has taken 5 days in `COLUMN B`, but in `COLUMN A` they only have 2 (2 days remaining for the year), in `COLUMN C` it needs to return 2 (as they are only allowed to be paid for 2 of the 5 days that took)

I have no idea how to do this...and its driving me mad!  PLEASE HELP!!

Comment: So even though this wont work I thought it would be something like:

=sumif(BL-BM<0,"0"),if(BN>0,"display value in BN")

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
=IF(A2<=0,0,IF(A2-B2>=0,B2,A2))
```

if you have overdrawn in column A it gives 0

if you have taken some, but not reaching over your limit, it gives number of days you have taken

otherwise (you have days remaining, but not enough to cover everything) it takes the remaining number of days

edit: changed the formula to show `,` instead of `;` as people apparently mostly use a different regional setting than me.

Comment: Hi there - thanks for your help!  however, its saying the formula doesnt work!  is it worded right, as in should there be commas or brackets in there?

You definitely have the right idea and that is exactly the working I would need to get the cell showing what I need!

Comment: Try to replace all Pavel_V delimiter:  `;` -> `,`. So `=IF(A2<=0,0,IF(A2-B2>=0,B2,A2))`

Comment: right, sometimes it seems to me that I am the only one here with this regional settings.

Comment: Hi Pavel, thank you so much for your help!  Its almost perfect! The only thing it doesnt do is give me the days in the third scenario - where the person is only allowed a certain amount of the holidays in B.

As in, if B has 5 and C has 8, it should only show 5 as they wouldnt be allowed to take 8 days holiday, only 5 as that would be the maximum left for the year!

Apart from that it is perfect!!

Comment: now I am bit lost - "if B has 5 and C has 8", what is column C? If you mean 5 in A (remaining days) and 8 in B (drawn in month), then it should give you 5 and that is what it gives.

Comment: A     B      C     WHAT C SHOULD SAY
-3 3 0 0
-3 3 0 0
1 5 5 1
0 1 1 0
-2 0.5 0 0
0 1 1 0
3 5 5 3
-1 5 0 0
-2 3.5 0 0
2 1 1 1
8 1 1 1
4 1 1 1
-7 3 0 0
4 4 4 4
7 1 1 1
7 1 1 1
8 3 3 3
7 2 2 2
3 3 3 3
   
1 2 2 1
-1 1 0 0
-3 5 0 0
-4 4 0 0
-4   0 0
4 1 1 1

As you can see, C

Comment: would be more readable if you edited your question and put it there. If I decoded this correctly than one of the issues is for example "1 5 5 1" correct? I am wondering how the formula would return 5 here, because for me it gives 1 as it should. if you go throught the logic of the formula : value in A = 1 is greater than 0, and column A (1) - column B (5) is lower than 0, so it should return column A = 1

Comment: are you sure that you have the last part of the formula correct? ",B2,A2))" because only way I can reproduce your list is if I have ",B2,B2))"